# Lilypond - Custom Key Signature for Turkish folk music and microtonal accidentals

Tags: theory, key, lilypond

I have to create this key signature in lilypond:

[image]

Would it be possible to create something like that?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
% LilyBin
\score{
    {
        \set Staff.keySignature = #`((-1 . ,FLAT) (3 . ,SHARP))
        \time 9/8
        \override Staff.KeySignature.stencil = #ly:text-interface::print
        \override Staff.KeySignature.text =
        \markup {
          \concat {
            \musicglyph #"accidentals.flat"
            \lower #0.4 \super \fontsize #-3 2
          }
          \concat {
            \raise #2 \musicglyph #"accidentals.sharp"
            \raise #1.6 \super \fontsize #-3 3
          }
        }
        s4.*3
    }

    \layout{}
    \midi{}
}
```

Lilybin: http://lilybin.com/ugfo88/1 
Thanks to *yoker* from IRC

Answer (score 2):

This works in latest stable 2.18.2

```
\relative c' {
  \set Staff.keySignature = #`((6 . ,FLAT)
                               (3 . ,SHARP))
  c4 d e fis
  aes4 bes c2
}
```

[image]

See http://lilybin.com/4i8zxe/1

Comment: For the current development version 2.19, the property is keyAlterations instead. Try \set Staff.keyAlterations = #`((6 . ,FLAT)
                               (3 . ,SHARP))

Comment: Am I missing something? I don't see any superscripts in the proposed solution.

Comment: You're right but in the comments nobody focused on the superscripts and I thought the key itself was the main problem. Also, the superscripts looked like footnote markings for some kind of explanation, more than an actual element of the signature. Anyway, I'm pretty confident on some ideas could came from http://lsr.di.unimi.it/LSR/Item?id=433 or http://lsr.di.unimi.it/LSR/Item?id=786 in which markups and custom key signatures are built.

Comment: No, apparently those are the actual accidentals; the superscripts indicate specific microtonal inflections. Is it possible to use a different font for the elements of the key signature in Lilypond?